# Difference between IE10 and Chrome calculating heights of inline-block elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I have a slightly modified Bootstrap Dropdown to truncate text within the button element, however, there seems to be a difference in how the height of the button element is calculated.

[This fiddle demonstrates what I did initially](http://jsfiddle.net/GPtDs/1/) The key seems to be the CSS controlling the span element within the button.

```
button.btn span {
    min-width:91px;
    max-width:91px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Below are the browser metrics for IE and chrome for the height of the button element:

[image: IE inline-block metrics]
[image: Chrome inline-block metrics]

Replacing the inline-block style on the span with a float: left [as demonstrated in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCBks/1/) appears to correct the heights and works across both browsers.

```
button.btn span {
    min-width:91px;
    max-width:91px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float: left;
}
```

[image: IE float: left metrics]

What is causing the difference in element height between Chrome and IE when using inline-block and which is doing it correctly?

Update: Firefox appears to do the same thing as IE here.

Comment: float force the element to left or right directions, display-block dnt force it make it inline only without forcing the direction of the element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you'll find your answers at this URL:

http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Note: did you gave a try to `display:table-cell`?

Comment: Setting display: table-cell; causes the little caret (see the fiddle in the original question for full details) to display on the next line. That article does seem to confirm what I've heard from other people about this though. Now just to try and wrap my head around it!